# Lint error in getting Bluetooth adapter

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am following documentation to Bluetooth Low Energy devices to scan BLE devices.

As mentioned in the doc, I defined ---

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;

final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = 
(BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);

mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter(); //Lint Error..
```

But I am getting a Lint error---

> Call requires API level 18 (current min is 8):
>   android.bluetooth.BluetoothManager#getAdapter

So I changed my code to--

```
mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
```

Is the code replacement for the above lint error ?

Comment: Currently Android only supports one Bluetooth adapter, so you can just use `BluetoothManager.getAdapter()`

Comment: Do you mean that I can use - `BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()` ?

Comment: Sure you can, but now it is does not make sense because the reason of above

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can call `BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()`. [BluetoothManager documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothManager.html) says that

*Use [getSystemService(java.lang.String)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSystemService%28java.lang.String%29) with [BLUETOOTH_SERVICE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) to create an [BluetoothManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothManager.html), then call [getAdapter()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothManager.html#getAdapter%28%29) to obtain the [BluetoothAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html).*

***Alternatively, you can just call the static helper [getDefaultAdapter()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#getDefaultAdapter%28%29).***

---

Or you can check build version and initialize `mBluetoothAdapter`, like below

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
        mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
} else {
       mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
}
```

Comment: Is there any advantage to using the BluetoothManager if you can always use BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()?

Comment: @ciaranodc If you look at the code of BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter() at http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.java , it does works for you. So same.